# Connecting MySQL Azure with Java

Tags: java, mysql, azure

I am facing an issue to connect to azure MySQL database with Java. Though whenever I am connecting with same database with MySQL workbench the connection working as expected.

To connect the same I tried below codes where used both of the url string mentioned.

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
// String url = "jdbc:mysql://***-mysqldbserver.mysql.database.azure.com:3306/medilegaldb?autoReconnect=true";
String url ="jdbc:mysql://***-mysqldbserver.mysql.database.azure.com:3306/medilegaldb?useSSL=true&requireSSL=false";
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "user", "pass");
```

[image: Azure Subscription Details]

Need help to identify the issue.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Did you open up port 3306 in both directions on your Azure instance?  You'll need to do that in order for your MySQL instance to be reachable from the outside.  And of course, please verify that you are using the right credentials.

Comment: Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure - This is the error I m getting. Also about credentials I am using the same configuration when connecting though workbench and everything working.

Comment: Problem I am getting is only with the Java configuration. Please suggest.

Comment: This problem is specific to mysql jar file. Now it's resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which version of MySQL-connector-java did you use? I used 5.1.6 and encountered the same error. But if I use 5.1.31, it works. Please let me know if this fix your issue.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.31</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Yes. This works fine for me. Thanks for the quick help.

Comment: can u please give a specific reason on this issue, as I have also facing the same